# Applying updates to Ubuntu 14.04 isn't working for one machine

Tags: aws

I was applying updates to my AWS Ubuntu 14.04 servers.  I used this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It work for all of them, except one server.

I get this error at the end:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried to do an upgrade.  I ran this:

```
# sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I saw this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  lxc-docker
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

What should I do to get the updates to apply?

Comment: Raring is 13.04, not 14.04. Perhaps you have some spurious sources, or you're actually on 13.04.

Comment: What should I do about spurious sources?  I am running 14.04.  I did this command to prove it: lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

Comment: Delete them. Do `grep raring /etc/apt/sources.list* -R`, find the offending entries and remove them.